# rails plugin install error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I a trying to install dynamic_form plugin for rails, using following command:

**rails plugin install https://github.com/rails/dynamic_form.git**

But I get the following error:

```
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/commands/plugin.rb:277: Commands is not a module (TypeError)
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:596:in `new_constants_in'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:17
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6
```

Can anyone help me on this? Thanks.

Comment: https://github.com/joelmoss/dynamic_form
did you tried this place ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They had some issues with rake 0.9.2. I found this solution:

https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/1866